# testing any webapp at db level

Tags: load-testing, web-applications, loadrunner

I wanted to know if there are any open source tool for load testing any web application.

Is LoadRunner a perfect tool from an  enterprise perspective for this purpose?

Comment: To shortly answer your question: Yes there are, numerous. LoadRunner is not part of that list as it's a commercial product, and it's target market is enterprises.

Answer (score 1):

Could you clarify your question a bit?   Are you looking to take the queries generated by the web application and then to reproduce them with a performance testing tool directly against the database or are you looking to exercise the web app and then analyze the database?

As far as what is best, this is a very subjective item and it comes back to that most dangerous of concepts, "requirements."   The requirements for one organization may point the way to one tool over another depending upon the technical needs of the application, the available skills within the existing/planned performance testing team and budget.   Mercury certainly made the case for the ROI for LoadRunner on the enterprise level long before it became part of HP's software offerings with market responding by giving it the largest overall market share.   However, as evidenced by it's non-monopoly position the requirements of other organizations have lead to the adoption of different tools.

Build your requirements; technical, skills required and business; then evaluate the various market offerings to see which one works for you.   The more interfaces you add the more compelling a commercial tool becomes over an open source one.    The greater your skills depth in your performance team the more flexibility you have in using an open source tool as you will need to build out some of the analytical pieces that a commercial tool includes by default.  ...